# Pulling in email via IMAP to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, imap

I am pulling email into my app via imap using Net::IMAP and copying the mail into an All Mail folder then marking it in inbox as deleted.

This then enables a backup of all emails for the user in All email folder and my app only pulls in emails from the inbox not flagged as deleted.

This works fine for gmail but i am trying to do it for horde webmail.

I successfully pull in the emails but cant seem to flag them as deleted and copy them to another folder.

Here is my code for doing this in gmail :

```
imap.uid_copy(uid, "[Gmail]/All Mail")
imap.uid_store(uid, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
```

Any one help with this? What should the "[Gmail]/All Mail") be changed to for horde webmail?  Is this different for all email like hotmail / yahoo etc?

Any help on this would be great.
thanks

rick

Comment: Horde webmail doesn't have a default archive folder, so you should probably create one the first time you try to archive an email, and then copy all the rest there. The code for deleting an email should be fine. Do you get any IMAP server errors back?

Comment: hi eugen    thanks for your help so far.       I get a Permission denied error when trying to create a mail box ?

Comment: You won't be allowed to create a new mailbox, but a new mail folder should be allowed. Can you post the exact code you're using and the exact error message you receive?

Comment: @eugen     this is my code begin
      # create the mailbox, unless it already exists
     imap.create('mailbox') unless imap.list('', 'mailbox')
   rescue Net::IMAP::NoResponseError => error
       puts "Error---: #{error.message}"
  end

Comment: and the error i get is just permission denied !    any ideas ??    thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
      connection.store( uid , "+FLAGS", [:DELETED]) 
      ...
      connection.expunge()
```

e.g. "**store**" instead of "uid_store" ?

I'm not using Horde, but the above line is working for me for several IMAP servers.

Also make sure that you call **connection.expunge** on the mailbox where you flagged the messages for deletion..!

e.g. look at the net/imap API for #expunge:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html#M001441